# Conversion of Java Object to Java source code literal

Tags: java

I'm looking for a function that converts basic Java Objects like Strings, doubles, longs, chars, (and maybe even arrays) etc. into Java literal Strings that can be used in Java source code, e.g.

```java
    String str = "hello";
    double d = 1.5;
    long myLong = 100L;
    int[] ints = new int[] { 5, 6 };

    System.out.println(toLiteral(str)); // prints "hello" (including double quotes!)
    System.out.println(toLiteral(d)); // prints 1.5
    System.out.println(toLiteral(myLong)); // prints 100L (including the L)
    System.out.println(toLiteral(ints)); // (bonus) prints new int[] { 5, 6 }
```

I would much prefer existing JavaSE or library code over a custom solution.

Comment: this is both interesting and weird. you might want to explain in your question why you need this, cause otherwise it is a XY problem.

Comment: may you can create your own method using `instance of` and manipulate a return string

Comment: @Eugene indeed, it's something I've never needed in > 20 years of coding Java - and then one gets that kind of situation, thinking there must be a method like that? The actual reason is, that I want to print method calls together with their arguments, not just for logging, but for a situation where a program flow needs to be replay-able, as code. The arguments are always simple arguments, but there are many different method calls. In a way, it's nothing weird, when thinking how JavaScript code and JSON are related and can be converted easily from JS objects to and from JSON (which is JS code).

Comment: Should this cover all Java objects?  Because there's no guarantee that all of the information that was available at an object's instantiation is still around.  For example, you could have a constructor like `public MyObj(String str) { }` where the parameter isn't used.  Then you can't instantiate the object without passing in an argument, but the original value of that argument is no longer there.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong it doesn't need to (and in principle probably cannot be) exhaustive, though the more it can cover, the better.

Comment: this information must be present in the constant pool, except the `int []`, it will only tell that it is an array, not the contents (which can be computed). Should be doable? But painful too, I bet there are edge cases that we do not see

Comment: @Eugene I keep thinking, that a method like that should probably already exist, in a library for either logging, testing, aop (for intercepting and logging method calls), or some code generator. Hopefully not some unnecessarily huge framework though, and ideally maybe already part of JavaSE.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a library method that could do a better job, I wrote my own solution, which covers the types I need. I included some primitive arrays, as well as Instants (with local timezone for better readability). Feel free to extend this with other useful types.

```java
import static org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava; // Apache commons-text
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

public static final ZoneId ZONE = ...;

public static String toJavaLiteralStr(final Object o) {

  if (o instanceof Long)
    return o + "L";
  else if (o instanceof Integer)
    return o.toString();
  else if (o instanceof Double)
    return o.toString();
  else if (o instanceof String s)
    return "\"" + escapeJava(s) + "\"";
  else if (o instanceof Character c)
    return "'" + (c == '\'' ? "\\'" : c) + "'";
  else if (o instanceof int[] ints)
    return "new int[] {" + convertArray(Arrays.stream(ints).boxed()) + "}";
  else if (o instanceof long[] longs)
    return "new long[] {" + convertArray(Arrays.stream(longs).boxed()) + "}";
  else if (o instanceof double[] doubles)
    return "new double[] {" + convertArray(Arrays.stream(doubles).boxed()) + "}";
  else if (o instanceof Instant instant)
    return "Instant.parse(\"" + instant.atZone(ZONE).format(ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) + "\")";
  else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown argument type: " + o.getClass().getName());
}

private static String convertArray(final Stream<?> boxedStream) {
  return boxedStream.map(o -> toJavaLiteralStr(o)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Comment: funny how you assume that everyone appends `L`... via that `return o + "L";`. I'll give you a 1+ for trying, but this is a very naive solution, which I assume you already know :)

Comment: @Eugene Agreed, the solution is naive indeed. Just as food for thought, however, the L isn't always as optional as it seems. Try `new ArrayList<Long>().add(42)`.

Comment: right, but your example had `long myLong = 100L;`

Comment: I've made adding the L to every long literal a habit, to avoid unpleasant surprises like in `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(42); list.remove(42L);`